# Concrete isomorphism between $\mathbf A\mathbf l\mathbf g(T)$ and category of commutative binary algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I need to find a functor *T* : **Set** $\rightarrow$ **Set** such that **Alg**$($*T*$)$ is concretely isomorphic to the category of commutative binary algebras.

The first idea is that the functor is likely to map object $X\in Ob($**Set**$)$ to the $X\times X$ because then we have to get a binary algebra, i.e., the operation $X\times X\rightarrow X$, which have to be commutative.

So the question (if these thoughts are right) is: how to map $X$ to $X\times X$ to get later a commutative binary algebra?

Comment: [In case anyone else was confused like me.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856131/on-the-category-of-sets-as-an-example-of-an-algebraic-category)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think you're still confused. Based on the OP's other questions, [e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456494/categories-of-mathbf-t-algebras), the OP intends the notion of [algebras of an endofunctor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+for+an+endofunctor). The choice of $T$ for the name of the functor is definitely misleading though, but not due to being confused for a theory, rather because $T$ is often used mnemonically for a monad (aka a triple) and algebras for a monad are usually more significant. Usually $F$ is used for the non-monadic case.

Comment: @DerekElkins "I think you're still confused." Not surprising. I probably should've just asked A. Gonus or Berci to clarify.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, yes, you are right, I intended this notion like in nCatlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Giving a function $f:A/\varepsilon\,\to B$ from a quotient set  $A/\varepsilon$ is the same as giving a function $\bar f:A\to B$ that satisfies $a\,\varepsilon\,a_1\ \Rightarrow\ f(a)=f(a_1)$.

> Apply this for $A=X\times X$ and a suitable equivalence relation $\varepsilon$ on it.